# how to save checkbox information in the db on Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have the following issue: I'm creating a form to register users on an application and within the different input types there are a couple of checkboxes regarding the language the user speaks. Now since the user might speak more than just one language I was wondering how is that handled in the db? Should I have lang1, lang2, lang3...etc as rows in the 'users' table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I have lang1, lang2,
>   lang3...etc as rows in the 'users'
>   table?

That's not a good idea. The table structure should be something like this:

```
user
-------------
| id | .... |

language
-------------
| id | name |

user_language
-------------------------
| user_id | language_id |
```

Then to, for example, get the user's language choices, this mock query would work:

```
SELECT language.name as language
FROM user
INNER JOIN user_language ON user_language.user_id = user.id
INNER JOIN language ON language.id = user_language.language_id
WHERE user.id = $id
```

This means you can update the language names and the name update will happen transparently without you having to worry about editing it in all instances of the user table. This method also allows you to assign as many languages as you want for the user.

***EDIT***:

Take for example if language is English and Spanish (id 1 and id 2), and the User's ID is 1. In order to associate the user with the languages:

```
INSERT INTO user_language (user_id, language_id)
VALUES(1,1); <-- Associate user with English (id 1)
INSERT INTO user_language (user_id, language_id)
VALUES(1,2); <-- Associate user with Spanish (id 2)
```

Now, this assumes that you're populating your available languages with the values in the `language` table, with the value of the field being `language.id`, and the display of the field being `language.name`.

Comment: @onteria_, sorry if my question is too amateurish but, how would I create user_language? I mean,... since all its input would come out of the other two tables... I wouldn't be creating user_id and language_id with AUTO_INCREMENT. Should I assign just INT(99) for both of them or something like that?

Comment: @la_f0ka `user_id` should be the same size as `user.id` and `language.id` / `user_language.language_id` could probably work as an `UNSIGNED TINYINT`, which gives you a max of 255, in MySQL at least. Don't really need anything bigger than that if you have just a few languages to work with.

Comment: @onteria_ , I think I'm still missing some point here (and not being that good with sql is to blame here, I know)...Suppose the user chooses English and Spanish. The 'user' table would be updated with all the information (mail, pass, etc)...in the language row...what would be there? Or is it there where the user_language table comes into play to store...the user id and (this is where I'm lost) the language'S'...because there would be only one field over there too, right?

Comment: @la_f0ka see the edit I just added to my answer, the explanation got a little lengthy for comments

Comment: @onteria_ , I think I understood now, this means that in user_language I could have two or more rows for the same user, as long as user_id is not supposed to be UNIQUE I'll be alright doing this kind of stuff. How would I be inserting this though? Since my form is all inserted at once...should I have a loop to insert the languages?

Comment: @la_f0ka You can create a UNIQUE combination on `user_id` and `language_id` by making it your primary key, since the combination of a user id and a language id should never appear more than once. Also yes, you will need to either loop to insert the languages, or you'll have to use the alternate syntax of inserting multiple values `VALUES(1,1),VALUES(1,2)` which is possible, but far less reader friendly depending on if it's easily supported with Zend_Db or not.

Comment: @onteria_ , ok thank you very much for your help. I'll check it out and try to figure wht's the best way to handle the multiple checkbox input in zf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a complete newbie in Zend myself (I'm a 4th year BSC student) but this is what I would do.

I would create a related table such as speaksLanguages having multiple rows in the users table that most will be null is never a good idea in my opinion, on saving the user have your application redirect to the speaksLanguages controller createAction() and save the users languages there.

You will need to create a session to persist the new user across the redirect.

Again I'm new to this but I've done something similar using this logic.